# The ELGG Themes Pluigins show This plugin is invalid: The required file "start.php" is missing. error

Tags: elgg

Hi I'm new to Elgg framework i'm looking for change the themes of the my site, i have used sea themes,pab_theme,puritythree_theme, and i was open the pluigins in admin page, i can't activated the themes

```
seatheme

This plugin is invalid: The required file "start.php" is missing.

Check the Elgg documentation for troubleshooting tips
```

the above message was show, so how can i will change the themes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every plugin (and themes are plugins) needs to have a start.php file in the root of the plugin's directory. So the path should look something like:
Elgg/mod/seatheme/start.php

The theme needs to reside in the mod dir, and it must have a start file. If, for some reason it doesn't, then you would get that error.

Are you really trying to load three themes?  Generally people only load one.  I don't think that this is the cause of the error though.

It would be good if you spent some time with the Elgg documentation, specifically: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Themes

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to elgg that's why i have installed three themes,and i use elgg 1.8 some of the theme only show that error message, at last i use cool theme,anyhow thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I found the solution. You have to download the zip file of the theme, unzip the file, open the file and if you find another file inside you must send that file to the mod file. Basically the directory would be Theme->Theme-> The rest of the files with start.php in it.

So you would have to send the second folder to the mod folder.